# Web API uri to routed and defined action returns 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, routes

I don't understand how `System.Web.Http` method attributes are used. I have this method `Logon` in my `Auth` **web API** controller (ASP.Net MVC 4):

```
public HttpResponseMessage Logon(string email, string password)
{
    User user = UserSrv.Load(email);

    if (user != null && user.CheckPassword(password))
        return this.Request.CreateResponse<User>(HttpStatusCode.OK, user);    
    else
        return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid username or password");
}
```

The *WebApiConfig.cs* file is default:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
    }
}
```

As is, a **GET** method returns `405 method not allowed`. As do a PUT, HEAD and all other verbs I've tried. But for a **POST**, it returns a `404 not found` with the following JSON:

```
{
"Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:8080/api/Auth/Logon'.",
"MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Auth' that matches the request."
```

}

If a add `[HttpPost]` attribute before method definition, I get the exact same results. With `HttpGet`, of course **GET** requests are OK. Combination of both attributes doesn't change anything. How come  **POST** requests are not correctly routed?

---

**Edit**:

The **POST** request does not match because the Uri is `http://localhost:8080/api/Auth/Logon`, with no query parameter. If I set default values for the `email` and `password` parameters, the method matches. But I thought that MVC was smart enough to match the request content to the action parameters. Do I really need to read the content stream to find the argument values?

Comment: Do you have an `AuthController`? And does that have the `Logon` method?

Comment: Yes, there is an Auth controller defined, and the first code sample is extracted from it, it's the Logon method itself.

Comment: There's no authentication of authorization attributes on that method is there?

Comment: There's a custom ActionFilterAttribute that looks for a custom header and returns 401 if missing, but that's not relevant. Removing it does not change the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's apparently impossible with web Api to bind a post request with multiple parameters to an action. The easiest solution is to send a json object and parse it. My method now looks like

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Logon(JObject dto)
{
    dynamic json = dto;
    string email = json.email;
    string password = json.password;

    User user = UserSrv.Load(email);

    if (user != null && user.CheckPassword(password))
        return this.Request.CreateResponse<User>(HttpStatusCode.OK, user);    
    else
        return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid username or password");
}
```

See http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/May/08/Passing-multiple-POST-parameters-to-Web-API-Controller-Methods
and http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Sep/11/Passing-multiple-simple-POST-Values-to-ASPNET-Web-API